# What's the point of instantiating a function when inheriting in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've always thought that when inheriting a prototype from another function, `Object.create(basefunc.prototype)` is the way to go. Another option would be `new basefunc()`, with the drawback of the base constructor being called.

But what's the downside of simply setting `thefunc.protoype = basefunc.prototype`?

Consider the following snippet:

```
function foo(){   
}
foo.prototype.blah = 1;

function bar(){
}
bar.prototype = foo.prototype; // instead of Object.create(foo.prototype)
                               // or new foo()
bar.prototype.constructor = bar;

bar.prototype.bleh = 1;

console.log(new bar()); // bar {blah: 1, bleh: 1}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VWDjU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did what you proposed, adding a method to foo.prototype adds a method to bar.prototype - which is what you want.  However, adding a method to bar.prototype also adds that method to foo.prototype- which is not what you want.  Adding a method to the child should not affect the methods available for the parent.

The reason this works is that bar.prototype and foo.prototype actually are referring to the same object.  It's not that you've created a copy based on bar.prototype, which is what you were intending.

You see the same thing with arrays which is why you'll often see code that like this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice()
```

Without that slice, changing newArray will also change oldArray. Like the example you gave, these variables both point to the same array in memory.